# How do you project a single non-repeating image across multiple UV sections across the originally created UV map?

Tags: texturing

The title suggestion told me my question appears subjective. Hopefully it's not.

Specifically I'm trying to go for an effect like in this video of 3D Coat, where a painted texture is projected (mostly) neatly across the UV image.  https://youtu.be/FiNASmArkxA?t=1176 The final product is meant to be used in a game.

Is this possible in Blender?

Comment: Blender has *Project from view" when unwrapping, that can get quick good looking results.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like a solution to make it look nice within Blender. Is there a way to project the image to look that way but with a less tidy UV map? So then the texture laid across the UV image looks crazy but on the actual object it looks like a single image. This is so the texture can be used for a game outside of Blender, and the layout of the maps can't be changed to fix any issues.

Comment: You can achieve a similar result in blender with project from view but it takes a little more work. 3D Coat extends and mirrors the "project from view" part all around your model, which you would have to do manually in blender.